# Dynamic generation of select clear other elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I have a for loop that creates as many  as I write in an input field. first time I write a number in the imput all is ok... he generates for example 3  fields. When I delete 3 and write 5, he add two objects but he also clear other... if I select an option in the first , I want to keep it selected when I add some other fields....

this is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/exv8s2sq

and this is the code:

```
Insert number<input type="text" id="number" name="number" ><br><br>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>$('#number').on('keyup', function () {
    changenumber(this.value);
});
$('#number').on('paste', function () {
    changenumber(this.value);
});


var now = 0;


function changenumber(val) {

    container = document.getElementById("container");


    var diff = val - now;



    if (diff > 0) {

        for (var u = now + 1; u <= val; u++) {


            container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML +
                " Select from options <select id='selectobj" + u + "' name='selectobj" + u + "' style='width:25%;'>" +
                "<option>A</option>" +
                "<option>B</option>" +
                "<option>C</option>" +
                "</select><br><br>";






            now = u;

        }


    }
}</script>
```

thanks

Lorenzo from Rome

Comment: What should happen if you first enter 5 then 3?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using innerHTML, i would suggest using jQuery as selector and use `element.append(selectbox)` to add new items. I've updated your fiddle with a working example based on your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/exv8s2sq/1/

There is also room to refactor your code a bit. When using jQuery, native javascript isn't really necessary for dom manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your elements in a div with a specific class so you can easily count how many items you already have. Then depending on the number you enter, check whether you need to add or remove elements from your container.

Use jQuery selectors all the way, it is easier to identify your elements, and use the methods it provides such as `.each()` and `.append()`

```
$('#number').on('input', function () {
    changenumber(this.value);
});

function changenumber(val) {

    if (val !== '') {

        // Wrap your elements in a div with a specific class
        var select = '<div class="select-wrapper">Select from options <select><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select></div>';

        // Count number of selects div
        var nbOfSelects = $('.select-wrapper').length;

        // Check if you need to add or remove elements
        if (nbOfSelects < val) {

            // Add an element
            for (var i = 0; i < (val - nbOfSelects); i++) {

                $('#container').append(select);
            }

        } else {

            // Loop through elements
            $('.select-wrapper').each(function (i) {

                // Remove an element
                if (i >= val) {

                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/exv8s2sq/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it adds an attribute of selected to the previous selected option using an onchange event listener

```
$('#number').on('keyup', function () {
changenumber(this.value);
});
$('#number').on('paste', function () {
changenumber(this.value);
});
var now = 0;
function changenumber(val) {
container = document.getElementById("container");
var diff = val - now;
if (diff > 0) {
    for (var u = now + 1; u <= val; u++) {
        container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML +
            " Select from options <select onchange='updateDom(this)' id='selectobj" + u + "' name='selectobj" + u + "' style='width:25%;'>" +
            "<option>A</option>" +
            "<option>B</option>" +
            "<option>C</option>" +
            "</select><br><br>";    now = u;
    }
}
}
function updateDom(s){
s.options[s.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected","selected")

}
```

Comment: you wlcm @LorenzoFioroni